# C# editing string

Tags: c#

Basically im sending this command to a vps using ssh.
"./script 162.249.73.1"

How can I execute the command on two ways, so the command will send the third parameter after editing it -2 and +2 so the command will be as the following:
"./script 162.249.71.1" and "./script 162.249.75.1".

Edit :

```
List<string> list = game.wmi_process();

            if (list.Count >= 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Thanks for using mygame");
                Console.WriteLine("IP_ "+ list[0]);
                Console.WriteLine("Port_  " + list[1]);
                Console.WriteLine("set time to play):");
                string time2 = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to Start the game ? (y/n)");
                string drop = Console.ReadLine();
                if (drop == "y")
                {

                    SshClient cSSH = new SshClient(xxxx);
                    cSSH.Connect();
                    SshCommand x = cSSH.RunCommand("./script "+list[0]);
                    cSSH.Disconnect();
                    cSSH.Dispose();
                }
```

so the list[0] will be the ip grabbed

now lets say it get 192.168.5.1 i want to get the same ip edited like that

192.168.3.1 and 192.168.7.1
i want to know how can edit xxx.xxx.thisone.x only thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the specific parts of your code you're having a problem with.

Comment: Why not just use 2 different strings, instead of trying to edit one?

Comment: not at all clear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step one: use `var arr = string.Split(new string[] {"."}, StringSplitOptions.None)` to get an array of strings. `arr[2]` should contain your number.

Step two: use Convert.ToInt32() to convert this string to an int.

Step 3: increase / decrease this int by two

Step 4: Write the number back to the were it was saved in the first place `arr[2] = number.ToString();`

Step 5: use `string.Join()` to join the strings back together

**EDIT**

My explanations might be a bit unclear, here the full code:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "192.168.1.1" };
var arr = list[0].Split(new string[] { "." }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var number = Convert.ToInt32(arr[2]);
number += 2;
arr[2] = number.ToString();
var result = string.Join(".", arr);
```

Comment: okey im noob with this but i did understand but i coudnlt implement it on my code can you post a full example of ur post ?